# Apple Care + Diagnostics

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know what's involved with the diagnostic test for iPhone for the Apple Care+? I'm thinking about getting it, but I want to know what's involved.

Answer (score 2):

They just send a code in form of a text to your phone, you accept the code and send it back. That's all.